# Solving differential equation $(2f(x)xy)'_x - (f(x)(2y^2+3x))'_y = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

We want to find all $f(x)$ that satisfy the differential equation:

$(2f(x)xy)'_x - (f(x)(2y^2+3x))'_y = 0$

I'm already lost in the beginning since $f(x)$ is a function of only one variable, I get:

$2xyf'(x)+2yf(x) - 2y^2f'(x)-4yf(x)-3xf'(x) = 0$

However according to my material, this should at this step equal $2y(f'(x)x+f(x))-4yf(x)=0$ which is clearly different, what have I done wrong? And how do I proceed thereafter?

Comment: is here $y=f(x)$?

Comment: Actually I should have added, we want to solve to find all functions $f(x)$ that satisfy the differential equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not get the term $-3xf'(x)$ in the $y$ derivative, as the original term $-3xf(x)$ does not contain any $y$.

The same goes for $-2y^2f'(x)$, when taking the derivative for $y$, the term $f(x)$ is a constant in the partial derivation.

Comment: That is true, thanks! But then we end up with $2y(f'(x)x+f(x))-4yf(x)=0$ and I don't really know how to proceed.

Comment: The next step is to see that this is the same as $2y(f'(x)x-f(x))=0$.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand how you got that

Comment: Because $-4yf(x)=2y(-2f(x))$.